MethodArgumentNotValidException is not getting caught in filter
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Using @ExceptionHandler com.ltfs.utility.exceptions.GlobalExceptionHandler#handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException)
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.Object com.ltfs.utility.controller.UtilityController.rpsGenerate(com.ltfs.utility.bean.RPSGenerateReq): [Field error in object 'RPSGenerateReq' on field 'applicationId': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.RPSGenerateReq.applicationId,NotBlank.applicationId,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [RPSGenerateReq.applicationId,applicationId]; arguments []; default message [applicationId]]; default message [must not be blank]] ]
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Using resolved error view: ModelAndView [view="{"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}"; model={}]
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Selected '*/*' given [*/*]
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - View name '{"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}', model {}
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Forwarding to [{"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}]
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Securing POST /{"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Secured POST /{"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - "FORWARD" dispatch for POST "/LTFSD2cApp/api/{"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}", parameters={}
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Resource not found
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource {"statusCode":400,"status":"Bad Request","errorDesc":"applicationId: must not be blank","errorCode":"MNDT_PARAM_ERROR","moreDetails":"Apologies, it seems mandatory parameters are missing from the request. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience"}.]
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
[2024-08-13 12:48:45] - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
DecryptedRequestWrapper requestWrapper = commonUtility.generateRequest(request, response, chain,
                            partnerRes.getPartnerDtlLst(), RATELIMITTHRESHOLD, jsonString, RATELIMITCHECK, ISLATE);
                    EncryptionResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new EncryptionResponseWrapper(response);
                    try {
                        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Exception Message: " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                    commonUtility.generateResponse(requestWrapper, responseWrapper, chain,
                            partnerRes.getPartnerDtlLst(), RATELIMITTHRESHOLD, jsonString, RATELIMITCHECK, ISLATE);
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public String handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String message = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
                .map(error -> error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage()).findFirst().orElse("");
        GenericErrorRes errorRes = new GenericErrorRes();
        errorRes.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        errorRes.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase());
        errorRes.setErrorDesc(message);
        errorRes.setErrorCode(MNDT_PARAM_ERROR);
        errorRes.setMoreDetails(MNDT_PARAM_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        
        String resJson = gson.toJson(errorRes);

        return resJson;
    }

}

@ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/RPSGenerate", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Object rpsGenerate(@Valid @RequestBody RPSGenerateReq appReq) 
{
}


Because it is being handled by the GlobalExceptionHandler so it will never be in the filter, which broke as you are returning a String, which wil llead to try to resolve a view. Add @ResponseBody to get the String as a response.

I tried with @ResponseBody but no exception caught in filter. Any solution for catching exception in filter class ?

As stated it won't be in the filter it will be handled by the GlobalExceptionHandler. If you don't want that don't use it.

Now I removed GlobalExceptionHandler still no exception caught in filter

Because Spring Boot also has an exceptikon handler. Why do you want the exception in the filter and by pass the exception handling of Spring? Why do you want to build your own instead of using the framework?

That wasn't the question, why do you want it in the filter. The exception handler will handle the exception (as it should) it won't propagate the exception as it has been handled.

But I am unable to fetch that response too in EncryptionResponseWrapper class which provides byte array of the actual response, but it is returning blank, because I want to further encrypt the response and send it to the output

Now that is a different question. You should add @ResponseBody so the exception handler will write the response, what I think is that you fail to override all the methods needed in your EncryptionResponseWrapper to catch the writing of the response (which is I think directly done on the OutputStream which you would need to intercept). So the problem is your own EncryptionResponseWrapper and not somewhere else and hasa nothing to do with the fact you see (or not) the exception in the filter.

I am able to fetch Controller Response in my ResponseWrapper class but getting blank response for ExceptionHandler class even when I use @ResponseBody on ExceptionHandler method

I don't care if that works or not, you are returning a different content type and that is handled differently and written differently. So if you haven't overridden all the proper methods in your EncryptionResponseWrapper it won't work. So please add that class.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
